# VS 2005 Can not open DataSet Schema in Designer mode

Tags: visual-studio-2005, upload, dataset, windows-forms-designer

I cannot view DataSet file in designer mode in VS 2005. When I try to it another solution it is ok but in one of my project solution I cant. The projects are c# class library projects in a solution file.
Is there any suggestion?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? Error message, what happens when you try to open,...

Answer (score 1):

If you are not getting any error then I guess its a setting problem. 
For resolving that go to View menu in Dot.NEt and click on Non-viual Controls or `Ctrl+Alt+Q` to enable the same.

Now you'll be able to view the `Dataset` in design view.

Answer (score 0):

Try traversing it for errors along the line of..

```
System.Data.DataSet ds = new {your dataset}

if (ds.HasErrors)
{
    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
    {
        if (dt.HasErrors)
        {
            DataRow[] drErr =  dt.GetErrors();
            foreach (DataRow dr in drErr)
            {
                DataColumn[] dca = dr.GetColumnsInError();
                foreach(DataColumn dc in dca)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(dr.GetColumnError(dc)); 
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```